# "...Отдаться сладкому ничегонеделанию - этой непозволительной московской роскоши" - что не так с падежами?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Можно наконец-то отдаться бездумью и сладкому ничегонеделанию - этой
>   непозволительной московской роскоши.

Можно оставить как есть?

Мне хочется: *непозволительной в Москве, для москвича(ей)*... Возможно, придираюсь, но что-то меня смущает.

А вместо невинного "отдаться" хочется "предаться"; тоже придирка?

Comment: Мне тоже кажется, что с Вашими изменениями будет лучше, правильней.

Comment: Проблема, что надо утрясать; автор ведь не видит своей ошибки... А "молча" можно править только орфографию и бесфакультативную пунктуацию.

Comment: "Утрясать" значит самому убедиться, что изменить нужно, а после этого попытаться его убедить? А так, я полностью согласен: на этом сайте правлю тоже только это, слова меняю, только если уверен, что так нельзя, и сильно меняю, только спасая плохо понятные ответы, когда автор не умеет сформулировать свои мысли (сначала разбираюсь, что он хотел сказать). Вот так сегодня с "кауркой" поступил. Убедился, что она пишет не ерунду, и переформулировал. Та, что писала о связи с финскими словами.

Comment: Утрясать - это, будучи убеждённой, убедить автора. А ответы, полученные мной здесь, помогают с аргументацией. Мне, кстати, предлагают столько правок, будто я читаю сочинение третьеклассника, тогда как передо мной многоглавная книга.

Comment: Galina, Вы должны внести ясность. О какой роскоши идет речь:  характерной для Москвы, но непозволительной для автора или непозволительной в Москве (варианты: для Москвы, для москвичей).

Comment: Автор уже принял решение - не в нашу пользу, хотя читает все ответы и комменты. Материал свёрстан. Теперь пошла тема ТЕАТР.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Можно наконец-то отдаться бездумью и сладкому ничегонеделанию – этой обычно непозволительной для Москвы роскоши.**

Только тогда спокойно можно **отдаться** мечтам и воспоминаниям, погрузиться в ту легкую задумчивость, которая слаще всего на свете. [Ф. К. Сологуб. Помнишь, не забудешь (1912)]

Отдаться – это интереснее.

Answer (score 1):

"**Предаться**" (тому или иному пороку) - правильнее (*отдаются* стихии на её усмотрение или в чью-то личную власть). С *роскошью* в оригинале вышел такой акцент: *есть в Москве такая роскошь, как безделье*, *которую некоторые кое-где сочли бы непозволительной* - если смысл в этом, то можно оставить. Если же хотели сказать, что в Москве это непозволительно, лучше сказать это прямо:

> "... роскоши, в Москве обычно непозволительной".

Comment: Стилист! ))) *которую некоторые*... Спасибо!